# initRequiringSecureCoding - swift

Tags: swift

I am using one function to save data on file:

```
    let data = NSMutableData()
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
            
    archiver.encode(Elements, forKey: "Elements")
    archiver.finishEncoding()
    data.write(toFile: dataFilePath(), atomically: true)
```

After updating to swift 5, a warning start showing up as below:

```
'init(forWritingWith:)' was deprecated in iOS 12.0: Use -initRequiringSecureCoding: instead
```

I tried to use:

```
    let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
    let data = archiver.encodedData
```

When I tried to save the info, it give an error:

```
'This decoder will only decode classes that adopt NSSecureCoding. Class 'Elements' does not adopt it.'
```

Any advise?

Comment: Think of `Codable` instead of old Objc`NSCoding`

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
```

with

```
let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(requiringSecureCoding: true)
```

Comment: I tried this before, but it is not enough as I nee to write on data file.

Comment: Anyone here can assist in this matter?